# withNavigationFocus throwing lint error - React Native Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6, types, react-navigation

I'm trying to use withNavigationFocus for a component as code been written in Typescript. ,

my component props

```
   interface IScreenProps {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, IParamsNavigate>;
  departments: NavigationNode[] | null;
  updateSearchCriteria: (searchCriteria: ISearchCriteria, stack: StackNames) => void;
  resetProductState: () => void;
  isFocused: boolean;
}
```

component

```
class SearchScreen extends React.Component<IScreenProps, IScreenState> {

.....

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)( withNavigationFocus(SearchScreen));
```

there is no build error , still in red line is showing in editor/IDE on searchScreen export. .I have enclosed error i'm facing below.

[image]

Please let me know how i can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationStackProp` (or the relevant one according to your navigator), not `NavigationScreenProp`

```
interface IScreenProps {
  navigation: NavigationStackProp<IParamsNavigate>;
  departments: NavigationNode[] | null;
  updateSearchCriteria: (searchCriteria: ISearchCriteria, stack: StackNames) => void;
  resetProductState: () => void;
  isFocused: boolean;
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/typescript.html

Comment: I'm using react-navigation v3. NavigationStackProp is not available. Pls suggest some other relevant solution